# Is there a way to search from the back of a string in python using regex or any similar method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have text that can take multiple different forms with dashes in them. Examples:

```
"'Super-rainbow' time to fight - 22-50t", "'m-m-m' title destroyer - 20t", "'eating food' spaghetti - 5-6 times", "'hype-time' john cena -ttl", "cat-food time - 25-26p".
```

I would like to take all the characters from behind the dashes near the end. such as `"22-50t", "20t", "5-6 times", "-ttl" , "25-26p`. Is there any good way to do this in python?

Comment: maybe split the string (by whitespace) and search the list starting from the end

Comment: in `john cena -ttl` there is no extra space `john cena - ttl`?

Comment: Use a regex that's anchored to the end with `$`.

Comment: Is this one text (with literal `"` in it) or a list of strings? If it's a list, where are the `[]` around it?

Comment: As a note, you should make your examples valid python as much as possible. Notice how everybody had to convert your examples to lists? Better that is done once in the question.

Comment: Are there a clear set of rules here? I can write a regex that gets most of it right. But why would "-ttl" be a result but not "- 20 t"? How do we know when the dash should not be part of the answer?

Comment: Comment to the OP that asked the question, yes you can use RegEx but it can be more fragile. If you pattern looks like what you pasted that I recommended the simple `rsplit` approach below. As a newer SO user, please make sure that if they answered your question, mark it as an answer. This tells others to stop answering and rewards the individual that wrote the answer.

Comment: What's the goal? You can match those with [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/snYDSO/1) *...dashes near the end* is a vague description, the pattern I linked matches anything from a hyphen that is preceded by a space and [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the part after space and before the next double quote (which is more or less guessing).

Comment: Lots of questions for clarification but you have not addressed any of them. You are not carrying out your part of the SO bargain between those who ask questions and those who answer them. "near the end" is meaningless. Nor do your examples cover all the possibilities. What about `"game of - 1-2-3"`, `"game of 1-2-3-"`, `"game of 1--2--3"`? You need to state your question in words, precisely. Examples are for illustration only. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) like so:

```
import re

strs = ["'Super-rainbow' time to fight - 22-50t",
        "'m-m-m' title destroyer - 20t",
        "'eating food' spaghetti - 5-6 times",
        "'hype-time' john cena -ttl",
        "cat-food time - 25-26p"]

for s in strs:
    last = re.split(r' - ', s)[-1]
    print(f"{s}:{last}")
```

Prints:

```
'Super-rainbow' time to fight - 22-50t:22-50t
'm-m-m' title destroyer - 20t:20t
'eating food' spaghetti - 5-6 times:5-6 times
'hype-time' john cena -ttl:'hype-time' john cena -ttl
cat-food time - 25-26p:25-26p
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text is as you have posted. Your text will be interpreted as a tuple.

You can do without regex using `str.split()` or `str.rsplit()`

```
txt = "'Super-rainbow' time to fight - 22-50t", "'m-m-m' title destroyer - 20t", "'eating food' spaghetti - 5-6 times", "'hype-time' john cena -ttl", "cat-food time - 25-26p"

print(txt)

#
 ("'Super-rainbow' time to fight - 22-50t",
 "'m-m-m' title destroyer - 20t",
 "'eating food' spaghetti - 5-6 times",
 "'hype-time' john cena -ttl",
 "cat-food time - 25-26p")
```

---

```
[x.rsplit(' -')[1] for x in txt]

#[' 22-50t', ' 20t', ' 5-6 times', 'ttl', ' 25-26p']
```

Comment: Technically `rsplit` with `maxsplit=1` would be more performant.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse thanks.. edited:) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103433/python-split-vs-rsplit-performance